# What is the best way to test for partially loaded web pages in django

Tags: django, testing, integration-testing

I know that in django integration, it is easy to test if a page would load successfully by making sure status code is 200. However, the project I am working on have pages that might partially load (certain sections of the page will silently fail to load). What is the best way to catch this situation? Is there a way to insert such error into the http response?

I know I can potentially do regex on the text on the page to check for things that might not load or I can probably check that name of certain css class exist. But that does not seem to be too robust an approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will greatly depend on your implementation details, but there are two suitable approaches to testing templates that may help you:

- If the partial page loading can be tested/triggered by using nothing more than template syntax, create test templates that conditionally print some text you can match against in the response, such as `WORKED` or `FOO`.
- If it's something that largely depends upon the context the template receives, then one-off test views, which you define alongside your test case and call directly by passing in a mocked request, work as well. In this case, you'll likely rely on the test view to raise exceptions if the page rendering won't proceed as expected, otherwise everything went well.
- Alternatively, you can even mix the two. In this case, you'll rely on the view to generate a HTTP response which you'll then check for some test text.

If that doesn't work, you can resort to overriding the templates. The general problem is that you can't rely on matching against text because it's global. The template can change and potentially cause your tests to misfire. What you can then do is have specific test settings that add additional directories for template discovery where you can provide different template implementations which contain text that does not change which would be suitable and safe for matching against in the test. The difficulty with this approach is that it does not neatly document itself, as opposed to the previous two approaches.